# Scatter plot on how to add color?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code could plot but it just has one color. So it could not figure out the color of 4 areas.

What should be added for it?

```
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
  %matplotlib inline

  plt.title("rate in four areas")
  plt.ylabel("rate") #Y axis label
  plt.xlabel("Year")
  plt.scatter(df['Year'], df['rate'])

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
  plt.show()
```

Comment: What are you trying to color?

Comment: try to color the area column.

Comment: It has 4 lines but the lines are the same colors.

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] and try and explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Is df_three a tuple containing lists, such that df_three['Year'] is a list in itself? Or does df_three['Year'] have three lists in each element, and you're plotting them all together at the same time.

If the latter is true, try

```
plt.scatter(df_three['Year'][0], df_three['co2'])
plt.scatter(df_three['Year'][1], df_three['co2'])
plt.scatter(df_three['Year'][2], df_three['co2'])
plt.scatter(df_three['Year'][3], df_three['co2'])
```

Not the most elegant solution but I'm not sure what you're doing because you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: It returns "KeyError: 0" and there is no plot at all.

Comment: Can you do print(df_three['Year'].shape, df_three['co2'].shape) and post the output

Comment: output is (645,) (645,)

Comment: Your simply plotting one list against another. It's not possible to distinguish different areas to plot with different colours from that data set. If you want to colour four quadrants of the plot, then you need to separate the data set into the four areas beforehand, then plot each one.

Comment: so it could not plot all the lines in different color in one graph?

Comment: I seperate it to three data set and now it has different color in one graph!! It solved! Thank you for the advice.